# c++ windows 7 get all profiles last logon time in non domain computer

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a Windows 7 machine which is in it's own workgroup
The machine have few local user.
Is  there a way in c++ to get the last logon time of each local user (including the users that are not currently connected)?

Comment: [Query the event log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385650(v=vs.85).aspx), E.g. event 528 for local logon

Comment: Event log saves the events for limited time, I need a way to get the logon time also in cases which the last logon time of a profile is older than the ability of the event viewer to log

Comment: You can configure logs to keep events forever (*Log Properties* -> *When maximum event log size is reached:* -> pick either one: *Archive the log when full, do not overwrite events* or *Do not overwrite events ( Clear logs manually )*).